# Trying to implement Diffie-Hellman key exchange in an android application but get an error

Tags: java, android, cryptography, diffie-hellman

Allright to be honest, this is just a copy out of the oracle documentation. this after i spent days of researching the topic of save encryption. i tried several tutorials including the one from [java2s](http://www.java2s.com)
which also gave me an error.

So i ended up at one post from stackoverflow who pointed to the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#DH2Ex) which i hereby tried to implement to an android studio project.

I'll post the error message below the code.

```
    package xxx.serversocket.encryption2;

/*
 * Copyright (c) 1997, 2001, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle nor the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.security.interfaces.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.interfaces.*;
import com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE;

/**
 * This program executes the Diffie-Hellman key agreement protocol
 * between 2 parties: Alice and Bob.
 *
 * By default, preconfigured parameters (1024-bit prime modulus and base
 * generator used by SKIP) are used.
 * If this program is called with the "-gen" option, a new set of
 * parameters is created.
 */

public class DHKeyAgreement2 {

    private DHKeyAgreement2() {}

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            String mode = "USE_SKIP_DH_PARAMS";

            DHKeyAgreement2 keyAgree = new DHKeyAgreement2();

            if (argv.length > 1) {
                keyAgree.usage();
                throw new Exception("Wrong number of command options");
            } else if (argv.length == 1) {
                if (!(argv[0].equals("-gen"))) {
                    keyAgree.usage();
                    throw new Exception("Unrecognized flag: " + argv[0]);
                }
                mode = "GENERATE_DH_PARAMS";
            }

            keyAgree.run(mode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void run(String mode) throws Exception {

        DHParameterSpec dhSkipParamSpec;

        if (mode.equals("GENERATE_DH_PARAMS")) {
            // Some central authority creates new DH parameters
            System.out.println
                    ("Creating Diffie-Hellman parameters (takes VERY long) ...");
            AlgorithmParameterGenerator paramGen
                    = AlgorithmParameterGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            paramGen.init(512);
            AlgorithmParameters params = paramGen.generateParameters();
            dhSkipParamSpec = (DHParameterSpec)params.getParameterSpec
                    (DHParameterSpec.class);
        } else {
            // use some pre-generated, default DH parameters
            System.out.println("Using SKIP Diffie-Hellman parameters");
            dhSkipParamSpec = new DHParameterSpec(skip1024Modulus,
                    skip1024Base);
        }

        /*
         * Alice creates her own DH key pair, using the DH parameters from
         * above
         */
        System.out.println("ALICE: Generate DH keypair ...");
        KeyPairGenerator aliceKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
        aliceKpairGen.initialize(dhSkipParamSpec);
        KeyPair aliceKpair = aliceKpairGen.generateKeyPair();

        // Alice creates and initializes her DH KeyAgreement object
        System.out.println("ALICE: Initialization ...");
        KeyAgreement aliceKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
        aliceKeyAgree.init(aliceKpair.getPrivate());

        // Alice encodes her public key, and sends it over to Bob.
        byte[] alicePubKeyEnc = aliceKpair.getPublic().getEncoded();

        /*
         * Let's turn over to Bob. Bob has received Alice's public key
         * in encoded format.
         * He instantiates a DH public key from the encoded key material.
         */
        KeyFactory bobKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec
                (alicePubKeyEnc);
        PublicKey alicePubKey = bobKeyFac.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

        /*
         * Bob gets the DH parameters associated with Alice's public key.
         * He must use the same parameters when he generates his own key
         * pair.
         */
        DHParameterSpec dhParamSpec = ((DHPublicKey)alicePubKey).getParams();

        // Bob creates his own DH key pair
        System.out.println("BOB: Generate DH keypair ...");
        KeyPairGenerator bobKpairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
        bobKpairGen.initialize(dhParamSpec);
        KeyPair bobKpair = bobKpairGen.generateKeyPair();

        // Bob creates and initializes his DH KeyAgreement object
        System.out.println("BOB: Initialization ...");
        KeyAgreement bobKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
        bobKeyAgree.init(bobKpair.getPrivate());

        // Bob encodes his public key, and sends it over to Alice.
        byte[] bobPubKeyEnc = bobKpair.getPublic().getEncoded();

        /*
         * Alice uses Bob's public key for the first (and only) phase
         * of her version of the DH
         * protocol.
         * Before she can do so, she has to instantiate a DH public key
         * from Bob's encoded key material.
         */
        KeyFactory aliceKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
        x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bobPubKeyEnc);
        PublicKey bobPubKey = aliceKeyFac.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
        System.out.println("ALICE: Execute PHASE1 ...");
        aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(bobPubKey, true);

        /*
         * Bob uses Alice's public key for the first (and only) phase
         * of his version of the DH
         * protocol.
         */
        System.out.println("BOB: Execute PHASE1 ...");
        bobKeyAgree.doPhase(alicePubKey, true);

        /*
         * At this stage, both Alice and Bob have completed the DH key
         * agreement protocol.
         * Both generate the (same) shared secret.
         */
        byte[] aliceSharedSecret = aliceKeyAgree.generateSecret();
        int aliceLen = aliceSharedSecret.length;

        byte[] bobSharedSecret = new byte[aliceLen];
        int bobLen;
        try {
            // show example of what happens if you
            // provide an output buffer that is too short
            bobLen = bobKeyAgree.generateSecret(bobSharedSecret, 1);
        } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        // provide output buffer of required size
        bobLen = bobKeyAgree.generateSecret(bobSharedSecret, 0);

        System.out.println("Alice secret: " +
                toHexString(aliceSharedSecret));
        System.out.println("Bob secret: " +
                toHexString(bobSharedSecret));

        if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(aliceSharedSecret, bobSharedSecret))
            throw new Exception("Shared secrets differ");
        System.out.println("Shared secrets are the same");

        /*
         * Now let's return the shared secret as a SecretKey object
         * and use it for encryption. First, we generate SecretKeys for the
         * "DES" algorithm (based on the raw shared secret data) and
         * then we use DES in ECB mode
         * as the encryption algorithm. DES in ECB mode does not require any
         * parameters.
         *
         * Then we use DES in CBC mode, which requires an initialization
         * vector (IV) parameter. In CBC mode, you need to initialize the
         * Cipher object with an IV, which can be supplied using the
         * javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec class. Note that you have to use
         * the same IV for encryption and decryption: If you use a different
         * IV for decryption than you used for encryption, decryption will
         * fail.
         *
         * NOTE: If you do not specify an IV when you initialize the
         * Cipher object for encryption, the underlying implementation
         * will generate a random one, which you have to retrieve using the
         * javax.crypto.Cipher.getParameters() method, which returns an
         * instance of java.security.AlgorithmParameters. You need to transfer
         * the contents of that object (e.g., in encoded format, obtained via
         * the AlgorithmParameters.getEncoded() method) to the party who will
         * do the decryption. When initializing the Cipher for decryption,
         * the (reinstantiated) AlgorithmParameters object must be passed to
         * the Cipher.init() method.
         */
        System.out.println("Return shared secret as SecretKey object ...");
        // Bob
        // NOTE: The call to bobKeyAgree.generateSecret above reset the key
        // agreement object, so we call doPhase again prior to another
        // generateSecret call
        bobKeyAgree.doPhase(alicePubKey, true);
        SecretKey bobDesKey = bobKeyAgree.generateSecret("DES");

        // Alice
        // NOTE: The call to aliceKeyAgree.generateSecret above reset the key
        // agreement object, so we call doPhase again prior to another
        // generateSecret call
        aliceKeyAgree.doPhase(bobPubKey, true);
        SecretKey aliceDesKey = aliceKeyAgree.generateSecret("DES");

        /*
         * Bob encrypts, using DES in ECB mode
         */
        Cipher bobCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        bobCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, bobDesKey);

        byte[] cleartext = "This is just an example".getBytes();
        byte[] ciphertext = bobCipher.doFinal(cleartext);

        /*
         * Alice decrypts, using DES in ECB mode
         */
        Cipher aliceCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        aliceCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aliceDesKey);
        byte[] recovered = aliceCipher.doFinal(ciphertext);

        if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(cleartext, recovered))
            throw new Exception("DES in CBC mode recovered text is " +
                    "different from cleartext");
        System.out.println("DES in ECB mode recovered text is " +
                "same as cleartext");

        /*
         * Bob encrypts, using DES in CBC mode
         */
        bobCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        bobCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, bobDesKey);

        cleartext = "This is just an example".getBytes();
        ciphertext = bobCipher.doFinal(cleartext);
        // Retrieve the parameter that was used, and transfer it to Alice in
        // encoded format
        byte[] encodedParams = bobCipher.getParameters().getEncoded();

        /*
         * Alice decrypts, using DES in CBC mode
         */
        // Instantiate AlgorithmParameters object from parameter encoding
        // obtained from Bob
        AlgorithmParameters params = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("DES");
        params.init(encodedParams);
        aliceCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aliceCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aliceDesKey, params);
        recovered = aliceCipher.doFinal(ciphertext);

        if (!java.util.Arrays.equals(cleartext, recovered))
            throw new Exception("DES in CBC mode recovered text is " +
                    "different from cleartext");
        System.out.println("DES in CBC mode recovered text is " +
                "same as cleartext");
    }

    /*
     * Converts a byte to hex digit and writes to the supplied buffer
     */
    private void byte2hex(byte b, StringBuffer buf) {
        char[] hexChars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
                '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
        int high = ((b & 0xf0) >> 4);
        int low = (b & 0x0f);
        buf.append(hexChars[high]);
        buf.append(hexChars[low]);
    }

    /*
     * Converts a byte array to hex string
     */
    private String toHexString(byte[] block) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        int len = block.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            byte2hex(block[i], buf);
            if (i < len-1) {
                buf.append(":");
            }
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    /*
     * Prints the usage of this test.
     */
    private void usage() {
        System.err.print("DHKeyAgreement usage: ");
        System.err.println("[-gen]");
    }

    // The 1024 bit Diffie-Hellman modulus values used by SKIP
    private static final byte skip1024ModulusBytes[] = {
            (byte)0xF4, (byte)0x88, (byte)0xFD, (byte)0x58,
            (byte)0x4E, (byte)0x49, (byte)0xDB, (byte)0xCD,
            (byte)0x20, (byte)0xB4, (byte)0x9D, (byte)0xE4,
            (byte)0x91, (byte)0x07, (byte)0x36, (byte)0x6B,
            (byte)0x33, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0x38, (byte)0x0D,
            (byte)0x45, (byte)0x1D, (byte)0x0F, (byte)0x7C,
            (byte)0x88, (byte)0xB3, (byte)0x1C, (byte)0x7C,
            (byte)0x5B, (byte)0x2D, (byte)0x8E, (byte)0xF6,
            (byte)0xF3, (byte)0xC9, (byte)0x23, (byte)0xC0,
            (byte)0x43, (byte)0xF0, (byte)0xA5, (byte)0x5B,
            (byte)0x18, (byte)0x8D, (byte)0x8E, (byte)0xBB,
            (byte)0x55, (byte)0x8C, (byte)0xB8, (byte)0x5D,
            (byte)0x38, (byte)0xD3, (byte)0x34, (byte)0xFD,
            (byte)0x7C, (byte)0x17, (byte)0x57, (byte)0x43,
            (byte)0xA3, (byte)0x1D, (byte)0x18, (byte)0x6C,
            (byte)0xDE, (byte)0x33, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x2C,
            (byte)0xB5, (byte)0x2A, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x3C,
            (byte)0xE1, (byte)0xB1, (byte)0x29, (byte)0x40,
            (byte)0x18, (byte)0x11, (byte)0x8D, (byte)0x7C,
            (byte)0x84, (byte)0xA7, (byte)0x0A, (byte)0x72,
            (byte)0xD6, (byte)0x86, (byte)0xC4, (byte)0x03,
            (byte)0x19, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0x07, (byte)0x29,
            (byte)0x7A, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0x95, (byte)0x0C,
            (byte)0xD9, (byte)0x96, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0xAB,
            (byte)0xD0, (byte)0x0A, (byte)0x50, (byte)0x9B,
            (byte)0x02, (byte)0x46, (byte)0xD3, (byte)0x08,
            (byte)0x3D, (byte)0x66, (byte)0xA4, (byte)0x5D,
            (byte)0x41, (byte)0x9F, (byte)0x9C, (byte)0x7C,
            (byte)0xBD, (byte)0x89, (byte)0x4B, (byte)0x22,
            (byte)0x19, (byte)0x26, (byte)0xBA, (byte)0xAB,
            (byte)0xA2, (byte)0x5E, (byte)0xC3, (byte)0x55,
            (byte)0xE9, (byte)0x2F, (byte)0x78, (byte)0xC7
    };

    // The SKIP 1024 bit modulus
    private static final BigInteger skip1024Modulus
            = new BigInteger(1, skip1024ModulusBytes);

    // The base used with the SKIP 1024 bit modulus
    private static final BigInteger skip1024Base = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
}
```

This section of code gave me following error code when i try to run it:

```
09-21 15:30:48.844 31805-31805/ch.moritzhuber.serversocket.encryption2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: xxx.serversocket.encryption2, PID: 31805
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ch.moritzhuber.serversocket.encryption2/xxx.serversocket.encryption2.DHKeyAgreement2}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void ch.moritzhuber.serversocket.encryption2.DHKeyAgreement2.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2375)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void xxx.serversocket.encryption2.DHKeyAgreement2.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What is the simple thing I don't see?

Comment: `import com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE;` won't work and won't do anything. What kind of line do you get the exception? Are you sure it is related to the code you've provided?

Comment: The only error Android Studio points out is at the code line import com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE; where it says cannot resolve SunJCE but this isn't even neded, its greyed out. why do they have so mani lines of code which are not be used? (grayed out)

Comment: i can't figure out something else which causes the error. i built a completly new project with just this lines of code in it. But now as you write so, there shuldn't be a problem with the code but with the setup behind. what is the meaning of: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void xxx.serversocket.encryption2.DHKeyAgreement2.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the SunJCE import?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, yes i did mark all the imports which are told to be unused as comment. Still get the same error message